# PRQA: How to ignore some specific files?

Tags: c, qa-c

I have a framework, which generates 7000 PRQA warnings. 5000 warnings are created by automatically created files. I want to remove those files from the analysis. How to do this? 
I tried:

```
qacli.exe pprops -P C:\my_project --sync-setting "generated_stuff\*.c" --set
```

This is not working, what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Currently struggling with a similar issue. The PRQA manual is lacking examples here. Actually the syntax is:

```
qacli pprops --sync-setting <setting> --set <value>
```

which in your case means

```
qacli.exe pprops -P C:\my_project --sync-setting FILE_FILTER --set "generated_stuff\*.c"
```

Hope that helps!

Edit: I didn't get it to work with wildcards.

```
qacli.exe pprops -P C:\my_project --sync-setting FILE_FILTER --set generated_stuff
```

works, though.

Answer (score 0):

From the integrated help:

> Using the textbfFile Filter, it is possible to filter out individual source files and folders. String matching is used, and so, for example, project/subproject will filter the folder /home/project/subproject, as well as project/subproject1.cpp.

So it uses a simple 1:1 string match, without wildcards or other advanced stuff.